# Capistrano cleanup task hangs some times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Why does the capistrano cleanup task hang sometimes and how can I fix it?

It get's to this point and just sits there:

```
* 2014-01-06 20:52:21 executing `deploy:cleanup'
  * executing "sudo -p 'sudo password: ' ls -1dt /var/www/jobfly/releases/* | tail -n +6 | sudo -p 'sudo password: ' xargs rm -rf"
```

The weirdest thing is that this only happens sometimes. Other times it executes just fine.

I have this as the last line in my deploy.rb:

```
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup" # leave the last 5 releases only
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that if I change `set :use_sudo, false` it doesn't hang anymore.

Comment: Well that was the cause of the problem. No issue since.